# One has to cook himself or themself?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammatical-number

Wanted to know which form is better and why

One has to cook himself?

OR

One has to cook themself?

Comment: Why would anyone want to prepare their own body for consumption? It seems self-defeating.

Comment: Thanks @BarrieEngland :D so it sounds like someone is trying to cook his own body .:) WHat would you suggest should be the correct sentence?

Comment: I wouldn’t use _one_ at all, myself, but, if you have to, then _One has to cook oneself_ might do. I imagine the context would make it clear that self-immolation wasn’t required.

Comment: There was an old joke when I was a kid: Did you hear about the man who ran over himself? He asked his wife to run over to the shops for him but she said no, so he ran over himself.

Comment: nice one. witty

Comment: @BarrieEngland [Autocannibalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-cannibalism). It's a thing.

Comment: "cook __for__ oneself". (If you don't know the gender)

Comment: @Mitch See my comment at Neil under my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be sure, it has to be:

> One has to cook **oneself**

(*Oneself* goes with *one*, neither *himself* nor *themselves*.)

The above sentence is grammatical, and makes sense. However, it *could* be ambiguous, as comments have already shown. Overcome that by including a preposition:

> One has to cook **by oneself**

Incidentally, the *one* - *oneself* structure is less common these days, especially in AmE.

Comment: Or _for_ oneself, perhaps.

Comment: @Neil I would agree with *for*. However, it could also introduce another ambiguity: *cooking **by** whom* is not the same as *cooking **for** whom*. I avoided that.

Comment: To say 'to cook by oneself' means that one is alone in cooking. It might imply cooking for your own meal or for someone else. That's ambiguity. Can you explain the ambiguity with 'for'?

Comment: @Mitch: Clearly the reverse: you haven't ruled out the possibility of two people cooking food for just one of them.

Comment: @Charles: I have no idea what you're saying. In everyday usage, one  commonly uses 'cook for'; 'cook by' is rare and means something special. Since the OP doesn't specify anything at all, the former is better, whatever the meanings and ambiguities you can come up with. I am saying this for non-native speakers (like the OP), so that they won't make the mistake of saying something that means something else than what they meant.

Comment: @Mitch: I agree with everything you said (and had already upvoted Neil's comment above to that effect). I was just pointing out that essentially the same ambiguity exists with "for" and "by".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:I have to do my own cooking.

Answer (score 1):

"One has to cook for oneself" would be good. "One has to cook by oneself" does not mean the same thing; it means you have to cook with no one else around, or no one helping you. "One has to cook for oneself" means that your food (that you will eat) must be cooked by you; no one will do it for you.

"You have to cook for yourself" is a common way of expressing the same idea, at least in informal speech. Depending on the context it could mean either the same as "one has to cook for oneself" (e.g.: 'If you live in this house you have to cook for yourself"), or "you" could actually refer specifically to the person being addressed (e.g. 'Since you are a vegetarian (and the rest of us are not), you will have to cook for yourself').

Note that above I wrote:
'"One has to cook for oneself" means that your food (that you will eat) must be cooked by you; no one will do it for you.'
Without even being aware of it I switched from using 'one' to using 'you', which feels more natural to me here. I suppose if I wanted to stick with 'one' I could have written:
'"One has to cook for oneself" means that one must cook one's own food, no one else will do it.'

Comment: Funny how *for* can mean *by* (of course it does) -- "*to cook **for** oneself* means that ... must be cooked **by** you;" -- read that again! One also could cook **for** oneself ("that you will eat"). There are two entirely different aspects.

Answer (score 0):

it should be "they have to cook by themselves" or "he has to cook by himself"